# Whois IP Addresses From Shell Script and Print in a table

Tags: linux, shell, unix, whois

I have an input file with IP addresses like:

```
106.1.2.5
42.34.74.34
173.23.74.34
```

And so on

I am decoding all the IP addresses from a shell script the code of which is as follows:

```
while read line
do
#nslookup $line
echo " "
echo "# IP Analysis Details For IP  $line #"
echo " "
whois $line |  grep OrgName || whois $line | grep descr 
echo " "
echo "Hostname Details....."
echo " "
dig -x $line | grep PTR | dig -x $line | grep in-addr.arpa
#dig -x $line | grep PTR | dig -x $line | grep in-addr.arpa
#whois $line | grep $line && whois $line
echo " "
echo         "*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#    *#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#"
done < websitedump.txt
```

It shows the details but I want the output to come in a table form where I can copy paste the result in an excel sheet also. What my desired output should be (an example):

```
106.1.2.5   | China Telecom | China | And so on
42.34.74.34 | Vodafone      | UK    | And so on
```

I should be able to copy paste the output and paste in an excel sheet which automatically comes in table.

Comment: Here websitedump.txt file is the input files with all the ip addresses from top to down.

Comment: did you mean `dig .. | grep ... || dig ......` ? And please take the time to read the [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/awk.html) , especially the section on `printf`. Good luck.

Comment: Why are you doing twice `dig` and twice `whois` per line?